# IOS Add subview on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, ios5

i have a problem when i'm trying to add subviews to a UIScrollView on viewDidLoad.

I'm using this code to programmatically add the UIImageViews to the scrollView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSInteger const_width = 100;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 4;
CGRect theFrame = [self.scrollView frame];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * const_width;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin,theFrame.origin.y,const_width,110)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cocoloco.jpg"];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    //[self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.tag = i;
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = 110;
    rect.size.width = 110;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(const_width * numberOfViews, 110);}
```

But i get the current view:

[image]

It seems that the scroll view frame takes its position regardless the 3 yellow tabs (that are a special TabBarController) so i get a wrong frame origin from the UIScrollView and therefore the UIImageViews are wrong positioned.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do it, but add the height of the frame to the "Y" position of your rectangle. Something like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin,theFrame.origin.y + (theFrame.height),const_width,110)];
```

Comment: but the problem is that the frame for the UIScrollView doesn't take into account that it's inside a tabBarController (the 3 yellows tabs below the navigation bar). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the scrollview below the navigation bar at the top, try

```
self.scrollview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Then position the table below the scrollview by setting it's origin base on the scrollview origin and height:

```
CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
frame.origin.y = self.scrollview.frame.origin.y + self.scrollview.frame.size.height;
tableView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: don't worry i finally found the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should move any resizing or layout of your UI to the -(void)layoutSubviews method and this should sort your problem correctly.